# How to find the overlap between 2 sequences, and return it

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to find the overlap between 2 sequences. The overlap is in the left end of the first sequences and the right end of the second one.
I want the function to find the overlap, and return it.

My sequences are:

```py
s1 = "CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC"
s2 = "GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC"
```

My function should be named

```py
def getOverlap(left, right)
```

With `s1` being the left sequence, and the `s2` being the right one.

The outcome should be

```py
'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Have a look at the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/difflib.html) library and more precisely at [`find_longest_match()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.find_longest_match):

```
import difflib

def get_overlap(s1, s2):
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
    pos_a, pos_b, size = s.find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2)) 
    return s1[pos_a:pos_a+size]

s1 = "CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC"
s2 = "GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC"

print(get_overlap(s1, s2)) # GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects):

```
d = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,s1,s2)
>>> match = max(d.get_matching_blocks(),key=lambda x:x[2])
>>> match
Match(a=8, b=0, size=39)
>>> i,j,k = match
>>> d.a[i:i+k]
'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC'
>>> d.a[i:i+k] == d.b[j:j+k]
True
>>> d.a == s1
True
>>> d.b == s2
True
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm is a nice method for finding one string inside another (since I saw DNA, I'm guessing you'd like this to scale to... billions?).

```
# Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching
# David Eppstein, UC Irvine, 1 Mar 2002

from __future__ import generators

def KnuthMorrisPratt(text, pattern):

    '''Yields all starting positions of copies of the pattern in the text.
Calling conventions are similar to string.find, but its arguments can be
lists or iterators, not just strings, it returns all matches, not just
the first one, and it does not need the whole text in memory at once.
Whenever it yields, it will have read the text exactly up to and including
the match that caused the yield.'''

    # allow indexing into pattern and protect against change during yield
    pattern = list(pattern)

    # build table of shift amounts
    shifts = [1] * (len(pattern) + 1)
    shift = 1
    for pos in range(len(pattern)):
        while shift <= pos and pattern[pos] != pattern[pos-shift]:
            shift += shifts[pos-shift]
        shifts[pos+1] = shift

    # do the actual search
    startPos = 0
    matchLen = 0
    for c in text:
        while matchLen == len(pattern) or \
              matchLen >= 0 and pattern[matchLen] != c:
            startPos += shifts[matchLen]
            matchLen -= shifts[matchLen]
        matchLen += 1
        if matchLen == len(pattern):
            yield startPos
```

[The link where I got the KMP python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117214-knuth-morris-pratt-string-matching/) (and a builtin, which will be faster for small problems because of the runtime constant).

For bleeding-edge performance, use a prefix table and hash windows of your string as base 4 integers (in biology you'd call them k-mers or oligos). ; )

Good luck!

**EDIT:** There's also a nice trick where you sort a list containing every prefix (n total) in the first string and every prefix (n total) in the second string. If they share the largest common subsequence, then they must be adjacent in the sorted list, so find the element from the other string that is closest in the sorted list, and then take the longest prefix that matches completely. : )

Answer (score 5):

[Longest Common Substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring)

```
def LongestCommonSubstring(S1, S2):
  M = [[0]*(1+len(S2)) for i in xrange(1+len(S1))]
  longest, x_longest = 0, 0
  for x in xrange(1,1+len(S1)):
    for y in xrange(1,1+len(S2)):
        if S1[x-1] == S2[y-1]:
            M[x][y] = M[x-1][y-1] + 1
            if M[x][y]>longest:
                longest = M[x][y]
                x_longest  = x
        else:
            M[x][y] = 0
  return S1[x_longest-longest: x_longest]
```

Comment: This is the best i can come up with:

Comment: left = "CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC"
right = "GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC"


def getOverlap(left,right):
    if left == right[::-1]:
        return ""
    else:
        for i in left:
            for i in right:
                if left[len(left)-i]==(right[::-1])[len(right)-i]:
                    if False:
                        continue
                    return right[:len(left)-i]

Comment: @anne You should put that comment in your post, so it's formatted and more readable.

Comment: Thanks. If i turn s1 and s2 around, then i should get the answer 'c', but i get the same as if s1 is the left one and s2 the right one.

Comment: The question is not about common substrings. It simply looks at the prefix of the first string and the prefix of the second string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pylcs`. It is very fast!

[PyPi repository link](https://pypi.org/project/pylcs/)

```
import pylcs

#  finding the longest common subsequence length of string A and string B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = 'We like shannonai'
pylcs.lcs_sequence_length(A, B)
"""
>>> pylcs.lcs_sequence_length(A, B)
14
"""

#  finding alignment from string A to B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = 'We like shannonai'
res = pylcs.lcs_sequence_idx(A, B)
''.join([B[i] for i in res if i != -1])
"""
>>> res
[0, 1, 2, -1, -1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> ''.join([B[i] for i in res if i != -1])
'We e shannonai'
"""

#  finding the longest common subsequence length of string A and a list of string B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = ['We like shannonai', 'We work in shannonai', 'We are not shannonai']
pylcs.lcs_sequence_of_list(A, B)
"""
>>> pylcs.lcs_sequence_of_list(A, B)
[14, 14, 16]
"""

# finding the longest common substring length of string A and string B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = 'We like shannonai'
pylcs.lcs_string_length(A, B)
"""
>>> pylcs.lcs_string_length(A, B)
11
"""

#  finding alignment from string A to B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = 'We like shannonai'
res = pylcs.lcs_string_idx(A, B)
''.join([B[i] for i in res if i != -1])
"""
>>> res
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> ''.join([B[i] for i in res if i != -1])
'e shannonai'
"""

#  finding the longest common substring length of string A and a list of string B
A = 'We are shannonai'
B = ['We like shannonai', 'We work in shannonai', 'We are not shannonai']
pylcs.lcs_string_of_list(A, B)
"""
>>> pylcs.lcs_string_of_list(A, B)
[11, 10, 10]
"""

#  finding the weighted edit distance from string A to B
pylcs.edit_distance("aaa", "aba")
pylcs.edit_distance("aaa", "aba", {'a': {'b': 2.0}})
pylcs.edit_distance("", "aa", {'': {'a': 0.5}})
#  weight['']['a'] means inserting a char 'a' costs 0.5
#  similarly, weight['a'][''] means the score of deleting a char 'a'
"""
>>> pylcs.edit_distance("aaa", "aba")
1
>>> pylcs.edit_distance("aaa", "aba", {'a': {'b': 2.0}})
2.0
>>> pylcs.edit_distance("", "aa", {'': {'a': 0.5}})
1.0
"""

#  finding edit distance alignment from string A to B
pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aaa", "aba")
pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aaa", "aba", {'a': {'b': 3}})
pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aa", "aabb", {'a': {'a': 2, 'b': 0}})
"""
>>> pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aaa", "aba")
[0, 1, 2]
>>> pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aaa", "aba", {'a': {'b': 3}})
[0, -1, 2]
>>> pylcs.edit_distance_idx("aa", "aabb", {'a': {'a': 2, 'b': 0}})
[2, 3]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a language-agnostic duplicate of this question, [Given two sequences, find the maximal overlap between ending of one and beginning of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60421326/1709587) (without the implicit contenxt of bioinformatics / DNA sequences) where it is noted that this problem can be solved in O(n) time. Since *this* question is specifically about Python, below is a Python port of [trincot's O(n) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60422853/1709587):

```
def overlap(a, b):
    if a == '' or b == '':
        return ''
    # Deal with cases where the strings differ in length
    start_a = 0
    if len(a) > len(b):
        startA = len(a) - len(b)
    end_b = len(b)
    if len(a) < len(b):
        end_b = len(a)
    # Create a back-reference for each index
    #   that should be followed in case of a mismatch.
    #   We only need B to make these references:
    backref_map = [0] * end_b
    k = 0  # Index that lags behind j
    backref_map[0] = 0
    for j in range(1, end_b):
        if (b[j] == b[k]):
            backref_map[j] = backref_map[k]  # skip over the same character (optional optimisation)
        else:
            backref_map[j] = k
        while (k > 0 and b[j] != b[k]):
            k = backref_map[k] 
        if (b[j] == b[k]):
            k += 1
    # Phase 2: use these references while iterating over A
    k = 0
    for i in range(start_a, len(a)):
        while k > 0 and a[i] != b[k]:
            k = backref_map[k]
        if (a[i] == b[k]):
            k += 1    
    if k == 0:
        return ''
    return a[-k:]
```

Note that this function finds the largest possible EXACT overlap between the end of `a` and the start of `b`.

When run on the example inputs from the question, it gets the expected result:

```
>>> overlap(
...   "CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC",
...   "GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC"
... )
'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC'
```