# Finding matching strings when comparing two lists

Tags: python, list, dna-sequence

I am trying to compare two lists to see if there are any matching strings within the lists.

lets say `list_1` is

```
['GAAGGTCGAA', 'GAAGGTCGA', 'AAGGTCGAA', 'GAAGGTCG', 'AAGGTCGA', 'AGGTCGAA', 'GAAGGTC', 'AAGGTCG', 'AGGTCGA', 'GGTCGAA', 'GAAGGT', 'AAGGTC', 'AGGTCG', 'GGTCGA', 'GTCGAA', 'GAAGG', 'AAGGT', 'AGGTC', 'GGTCG', 'GTCGA', 'TCGAA', 'GAAG', 'AAGG', 'AGGT', 'GGTC', 'GTCG', 'TCGA', 'CGAA', 'GAA', 'AAG', 'AGG', 'GGT', 'GTC', 'TCG', 'CGA', 'GAA', 'GA', 'AA', 'AG', 'GG', 'GT', 'TC', 'CG', 'GA', 'AA', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'A']
```

and `list_2` is

```
['CCTCGGGA', 'CCTCGGG', 'CTCGGGA', 'CCTCGG', 'CTCGGG', 'TCGGGA', 'CCTCG', 'CTCGG', 'TCGGG', 'CGGGA', 'CCTC', 'CTCG', 'TCGG', 'CGGG', 'GGGA', 'CCT', 'CTC', 'TCG', 'CGG', 'GGG', 'GGA', 'CC', 'CT', 'TC', 'CG', 'GG', 'GG', 'GA', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'CCTCGGG', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I know that "TCG" is in both lists, but what type of function can I use to determine this within python? I tried a for loop and many other built in functions but I can't get it to work.

Comment: you just need a `boolean` as result ?

Comment: I don't get what having two lists has to do with this.

Comment: So you want substring matching?

Comment: substring matching, yes. I couldnt think of a word for it. I can probably find it online now. Thank you.

Comment: To me, lists have nothing to do with it, and I vote this as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128763/how-to-find-the-overlap-between-2-sequences-and-return-it

Comment: Do you want to match strings that only partially match?

Answer (score 7):

This is actually easy with [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

```
print set(list_1) & set(list_2)
print bool(set(list_1) & set(list_2))
# set(['A', 'C', 'G', 'CG', 'GG', 'T', 'GA', 'TCG', 'TC']) //common strings
# true //Boolean result
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/y0GltE

Comment: Would it be possible to only print the larges common substring?

Comment: What do you mean by **"larges common substring"** ?

Comment: without appropriate error checking: `sorted(set(list_1) & set(list_2), reverse=True)[0]`

Comment: I ended up going with a for loop because it worked better for what I was trying to do. If i wanted to print two matches if they were the same length, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 4):

`bool(set(list_1) & set(list_2))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using for loops if you need more than a boolean variable.

```
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if item1 == item2:
            print item1
```