# Strange behaviour of Python difflib library for sequence matcher

Tags: python, biopython, difflib, rosalind

I am somewhat puzzled by a strange behaviour in the `difflib` library. I try to find overlapping sequences in strings (actually Fasta sequences from a Rosalind task) to glue them together. The code [adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14128905/8881141) works well with a smaller length of the string (for the sake of the clarity, I construct here an example from a common substring `a`):

```
import difflib

def glue(seq1, seq2):     
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, seq1, seq2)
    start1, start2, overlap = s.find_longest_match(0, len(seq1), 0, len(seq2)) 
    if start1 + overlap == len(seq1) and start2 == 0:
        return seq1 + seq2[overlap:]
    #no overlap found, return -1
    return -1


a = "ABCDEFG"
s1 = "XXX" + a
s2 = a + "YYY"

print(glue(s1, s2))
```

Output

```
XXXABCDEFGYYY
```

But when the string is longer, `difflib` doesn't find the match any more.

```
a = "AGGTGTGCCTGTGTCTATACATCGTACGCGGGAAGGTCCAAGTTAACATGGGGTACTGTAATGCACACGTACGCGGGAAGGTCCAAGTTAACTACGAAACGCGAGCCCATCTTTGCCGGTGTTAACTTGCTGTCAGGTGTTTGGCAAGGATCTTTGTTTGCCGGTGTTAACTTGCTGTCAGGTGTTTGGCCGGTGTTAACTTGCTGTCAGATGCGCGCCACGGCCAAATTCTAGGCACGCCAAATTCTAGGCACTTTAAGTGGTTCGATGATCCACGATGGTAAGCCAGCCGTACTTGC"

s1 = "XXX" + a
s2 = a + "YYY"

print(glue(s1, s2))
```

Output

```
-1
```

Why does this happen and how can you use `difflib` with longer strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that this behaviour starts, when the "ATCG" string is longer than 200. Looking for this number on the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html) documentation page brought me to this passage:

> Automatic junk heuristic: SequenceMatcher supports a heuristic that
>   automatically treats certain sequence items as junk. The heuristic
>   counts how many times each individual item appears in the sequence. If
>   an item’s duplicates (after the first one) account for more than 1% of
>   the sequence and the sequence is at least 200 items long, this item is
>   marked as “popular” and is treated as junk for the purpose of sequence
>   matching. This heuristic can be turned off by setting the autojunk
>   argument to False when creating the SequenceMatcher.

Since the sequence only contains `ATCG`, they are of course more than 1% of a sequence of 200 characters and hence considered junk. Changing the code to

```
import difflib

def glue(seq1, seq2):     
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, seq1, seq2, autojunk = False)
    start1, start2, overlap = s.find_longest_match(0, len(seq1), 0, len(seq2)) 
    if start1 + overlap == len(seq1) and start2 == 0:
        return seq1 + seq2[overlap:]
    return -1
```

gets rid of this behaviour and allows for substring matching without restriction.
I thought I leave this here on SO, because I wasted hours combing through my code to find this problem.