# Given two sequences, find the maximal overlap between ending of one and beginning of the other

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I need to find an efficient (pseudo)code to solve the following problem:

Given two arrays of (not necessarily distinct) elements `(a[1], a[2], ..., a[n])` and `(b[1], b[2], ..., b[m])`, find the maximum `d` such that `a[n-d+1] == b[1]`, `a[n-d+2] == b[2]`, ..., and `a[n] == b[d]`.

For instance, given `a = [7, 8, 9, 8, 9]` and `b = [8, 9, 7, 8, 8]`, the result should be 2, since the maximal overlap (illustrated below) is 2 elements:

```
[7, 8, 9, 8, 9]
         [8, 9, 7, 8, 8]
```

I suspect an efficient algorithm exists (maybe `O(n)`?), but I cannot come up with something that is not `O(n^2)`. The `O(n^2)` approach would be the obvious loop on `d` and then an inner loop on the items to check the required condition until hitting the maximum `d`. But I suspect something better than this is possible.

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is a variation on string matching, which can be solved with a variation on the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm). The running time would be O(m+n) where `m` is the number of elements in `a`, and `n` is the number of elements in `b`. Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient experience with KMP to tell you how to adapt it.

Comment: @user3386109 my solution is also a variation of a string matching algorithm called [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) as the hash function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize the [z algorithm](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107), a linear time (***O***(n)) algorithm that:

> Given a string *S* of length n, the Z Algorithm produces an array *Z*
>   where *Z[i]* is the length of the longest substring starting from *S[i]*
>   which is also a prefix of *S*

You need to concatenate your arrays (*b*+*a*) and run the algorithm on the resulting constructed array till the first *i* such that *Z[i]*+*i* == *m*+*n*.

For example, for *a* = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3] & *b* = [2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 0], the concatenation would be [2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3] which would yield *Z[10]* = 2 fulfilling *Z[i]* + *i* = 12 = *m* + *n*.

Comment: Using the Z algorithm should work, but IMO the algorithm presented by trincot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60422853/1709587 is much easier to understand than the Z algorithm (and more specialized to the particular problem posed in this question). I had to go and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mzNnEGimPA (it's not great, but it gets there eventually!) to finally grasp the idea behind how earlier elements in the Z array are used to provide a "head start" calculating later ones; it wasn't obvious to me at all!

Comment: Also, one nit - you need to check not only that `Z[i]+i == m+n` but also that `i >= m` and `i >= n`. Otherwise you risk finding an "overlap" that actually contains more than the entirety of one of the strings. (The simplest failure case when following this answer literally is when trying to find the overlap of two strings consisting of the same repeated character, e.g. `aaaaaaaaa` with `aaaaaaaaaaa`. As written, this answer will find an "overlap" of `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` which is clearly not right!)

Answer (score 3):

For O(n) time/space complexity, the trick is to evaluate hashes for each subsequence. Consider the array `b`:

```
[b1 b2 b3 ... bn]
```

Using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), you can evaluate all the possible hashes for each subsequence. Pick a base value `B` (bigger than any value in both of your arrays):

```
from b1 to b1 = b1 * B^1
from b1 to b2 = b1 * B^1 + b2 * B^2
from b1 to b3 = b1 * B^1 + b2 * B^2 + b3 * B^3
...
from b1 to bn = b1 * B^1 + b2 * B^2 + b3 * B^3 + ... + bn * B^n
```

(This assumes your array elements are integers; if not, just map each distinct element to a unique integer beforehand.)

Note that you can evaluate each sequence in O(1) time, using the result of the previous sequence, hence all the job costs O(n).

Now you have an array `Hb = [h(b1), h(b2), ... , h(bn)]`, where `Hb[i]` is the hash from `b1` until `bi`.

Do the same thing for the array `a`, but with a little trick:

```
from an to an   =  (an   * B^1)
from an-1 to an =  (an-1 * B^1) + (an * B^2)
from an-2 to an =  (an-2 * B^1) + (an-1 * B^2) + (an * B^3)
...
from a1 to an   =  (a1   * B^1) + (a2 * B^2)   + (a3 * B^3) + ... + (an * B^n)
```

You must note that, when you step from one sequence to another, you multiply the whole previous sequence by B and add the new value multiplied by B. For example:

```
from an to an =    (an   * B^1)

for the next sequence, multiply the previous by B: (an * B^1) * B = (an * B^2)
now sum with the new value multiplied by B: (an-1 * B^1) + (an * B^2) 
hence:

from an-1 to an =  (an-1 * B^1) + (an * B^2)
```

Now you have an array `Ha = [h(an), h(an-1), ... , h(a1)]`, where `Ha[i]` is the hash from `ai` until `an`.

Now, you can compare `Ha[d] == Hb[d]` for all `d` values from n to 1, if they match, you have your answer.

---

> **ATTENTION**: this is a hash method, the values can be large and you may have to use a [fast exponentiation method and modular arithmetics](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation), which may (hardly) give you **collisions**, making this method not totally safe. A good practice is to pick a base `B` as a really big prime number (at least bigger than the biggest value in your arrays). You should also be careful as the limits of the numbers may overflow at each step, so you'll have to use (modulo `K`) in each operation (where `K` can be a prime bigger than `B`).

This means that two different sequences **might** have the same hash, but two equal sequences will **always** have the same hash.

Comment: Can you please start this answer with an assessment of the resource requirements?

Comment: This is a rather neat idea, but if the hashes have a type of fixed size then as you say they're bound to overflow and there's a collision risk (the severity of which you don't quantify and is non-obvious to me), and if instead the hashes have a variable-size type like `BigInteger`, then I imagine it's no longer an O(n) algorithm at all (in either time or space) since the hashes are going to get increasingly enormous (namely an order of magnitude bigger per element in the array). So I learned a cool trick, but in an actual program I would never use this; trincot's answer is far more practical.

Comment: You can use modulo in the hashes with a big prime number to avoid this,

Comment: @Daniel That just introduces the same kind of collision risk as automatically wrapping around due to overflowing the size of the type, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

This can indeed be done in linear time, *O(n)*, and *O(n)* extra space. I will assume the input arrays are character strings, but this is not essential.

A naive method would -- after matching *k* characters that are equal -- find a character that does not match, and go back *k-1* units in *a*, reset the index in *b*, and then start the matching process from there. This clearly represents a *O(n²)* worst case.

To avoid this backtracking process, we can observe that going back is not useful if we have not encountered the b[0] character while scanning the last *k-1* characters. If we *did* find that character, then backtracking to that position would only be useful, if in that *k* sized substring we had a periodic repetition.

For instance, if we look at substring "abcabc" somewhere in *a*, and *b* is "abcabd", and we find that the final character of *b* does not match, we must consider that a successful match might start at the second "a" in the substring, and we should move our current index in *b* back accordingly before continuing the comparison.

The idea is then to do some preprocessing based on string *b* to log back-references in *b* that are useful to check when there is a mismatch. So for instance, if *b* is "acaacaacd", we could identify these 0-based backreferences (put below each character):

```
index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
b:     a c a a c a a c d
ref:   0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 5
```

For example, if we have *a* equal to "acaacaaca" the first mismatch happens on the final character. The above information then tells the algorithm to go back in *b* to index 5, since "acaac" is common. And then with only changing the current index in *b* we can continue the matching at the current index of *a*. In this example the match of the final character then succeeds.

With this we can optimise the search and make sure that the index in *a* can always progress forwards.

Here is an implementation of that idea in JavaScript, using the most basic syntax of that language only:

```js
function overlapCount(a, b) {
    // Deal with cases where the strings differ in length
    let startA = 0;
    if (a.length > b.length) startA = a.length - b.length;
    let endB = b.length;
    if (a.length < b.length) endB = a.length;
    // Create a back-reference for each index
    //   that should be followed in case of a mismatch.
    //   We only need B to make these references:
    let map = Array(endB);
    let k = 0; // Index that lags behind j
    map[0] = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < endB; j++) {
        if (b[j] == b[k]) {
            map[j] = map[k]; // skip over the same character (optional optimisation)
        } else {
            map[j] = k;
        }
        while (k > 0 && b[j] != b[k]) k = map[k]; 
        if (b[j] == b[k]) k++;
    }
    // Phase 2: use these references while iterating over A
    k = 0;
    for (let i = startA; i < a.length; i++) {
        while (k > 0 && a[i] != b[k]) k = map[k];
        if (a[i] == b[k]) k++;
    }
    return k;
}

console.log(overlapCount("ababaaaabaabab", "abaababaaz")); // 7
```

Although there are nested `while` loops, these do not have more iterations in total than *n*. This is because the value of *k* strictly decreases in the `while` body, and cannot become negative. This can only happen when `k++` was executed that many times to give enough room for such decreases. So all in all, there cannot be more executions of the `while` body than there are `k++` executions, and the latter is clearly O(n).

To complete, here you can find the same code as above, but in an interactive snippet: you can input your own strings and see the result interactively:

```js
function overlapCount(a, b) {
    // Deal with cases where the strings differ in length
    let startA = 0;
    if (a.length > b.length) startA = a.length - b.length;
    let endB = b.length;
    if (a.length < b.length) endB = a.length;
    // Create a back-reference for each index
    //   that should be followed in case of a mismatch.
    //   We only need B to make these references:
    let map = Array(endB);
    let k = 0; // Index that lags behind j
    map[0] = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < endB; j++) {
        if (b[j] == b[k]) {
            map[j] = map[k]; // skip over the same character (optional optimisation)
        } else {
            map[j] = k;
        }
        while (k > 0 && b[j] != b[k]) k = map[k]; 
        if (b[j] == b[k]) k++;
    }
    // Phase 2: use these references while iterating over A
    k = 0;
    for (let i = startA; i < a.length; i++) {
        while (k > 0 && a[i] != b[k]) k = map[k];
        if (a[i] == b[k]) k++;
    }
    return k;
}

// I/O handling

let [inputA, inputB] = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let output = document.querySelector("pre");

function refresh() {
    let a = inputA.value;
    let b = inputB.value;
    let count = overlapCount(a, b);
    let padding = a.length - count;
    // Apply some HTML formatting to highlight the overlap:
    if (count) {
        a = a.slice(0, -count) + "<b>" + a.slice(-count) + "</b>";
        b = "<b>" + b.slice(0, count) + "</b>" + b.slice(count);
    }
    output.innerHTML = count + " overlapping characters:\n" + 
                         a + "\n" + 
                         " ".repeat(padding) + b;
}

document.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace }
b { background:yellow }
input { width: 90% }
```

```html
a: <input value="acacaacaa"><br>
b: <input value="acaacaacd"><br>
<pre></pre>
```